# Magento 2 : update the price value in shopping cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, price

How can we update the price value in shopping cart page for magento 2?

Comment: Please follow the below link it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721583/changing-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Comment: can you want to add extra fee in cart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can able to change the product price after add to cart using  an event called 'checkout_cart_product_add_after'.

Please follow the below link it will help you.

**https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-set-custom-price-of-product/**

Comment: i want ot use the same logic in  checkout_cart_update_items_before so how can i get $item and $item->getProduct() could you please give me the syntax. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to add extra fee in cart, then you have to make changes in total.php in model

```
class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
   /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */
    protected $quoteValidator = null; 

    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator)
    {
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
    }
  public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total) 
{
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);


        $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
        $fee = -10; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

        $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

        $total->setFee($balance);
        $total->setBaseFee($balance);

        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


        return $this;
    } 

    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total)
    {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Fee',
            'value' => 10
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('Fee');
    }
```

like this you can add extra fee.